# Using the solve_ivp() to solve the equations of motions

Tags: python

I have written a class that solves a physical system. My solve-method should not return anything. My code for the method is

```
    def solve(self, y0, T, dt, angle='rad'):
        time_points = np.linspace(0, T, int(T/dt)+1)
        if angle == 'deg':
            y0 = y0[0] * pi / 180, y0[1] * pi / 180
        elif angle != 'rad':
            raise ValueError(
                f"Invalid argument {angle} for 'angles' in 'solve'," +
                " must be 'deg' or 'rad'.")
        sol = solve_ivp(self, (0, T), y0, t_eval=time_points)
        self._t, y = sol.t, sol.y
        self._theta, self._omega = y[0], y[1]
```

when runing the code with the instance

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pendulum = Pendulum(L=2.7)
    pendulum.solve((1, 1), 50, 0.5)

    plt.plot(pendulum.t, pendulum.y[0])
    plt.show()
```

I get the following error-message

File "pendulum.py", line 70, in y
return - self.L * cos(self.theta)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

my code for y is:

```
    @property
    def y(self):
    """
    Translating angles into cartesian coordinates
    y is an array of vertical positions

    """
    return - self.L * cos(self.theta)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that your solve method should not return anything yet you use `result` to store the return value. The error is correct
What you need to do is change this

```
    def solve(self, y0, T, dt, angle='rad'):
        time_points = np.linspace(0, T, int(T/dt)+1)
        if angle == 'deg':
            y0 = y0[0] * pi / 180, y0[1] * pi / 180
        elif angle != 'rad':
            raise ValueError(
                f"Invalid argument {angle} for 'angles' in 'solve'," +
                " must be 'deg' or 'rad'.")
        sol = solve_ivp(self, (0, T), y0, t_eval=time_points)
        self.t, y = sol.t, sol.y  # Notice self.t not self._t
        self._theta, self._omega = y[0], y[1]
```

And

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pendulum = Pendulum(L=2.7)
    pendulum.solve((1, 1), 50, 0.5) #Does not return anything

    plt.plot(pendulum.t, pendulum.u[0])  # We attached the result to instance , we didn't returned it
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are assigning the return value of a function that returns nothing to a variable, then trying to access that variable's attribute `t`. If you assign the return value of a function that doesn't return anything to a variable, it gets assigned the value `none`. `none` does not have any attributes, hence trying to access `t` throws a `AttributeError`. If you want to access the member variables `t` and `u`, which I'm assuming belong to your class Pendulum, you will want to do this -

```
plt.plot(pendulum.t, pendulum.u[0])
```